# Webpack bundle analyzer "+ n Modules"

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I would like to learn how my angular code is bundled and to which chunk files. Therefore I'm using  "Webpack bundle analyzer". For some modules it's written in the report as: `router.js + "12 Modules"`.

How can I determine the contents of the `12 Modules`? I clicked on the line and it didn't help.

[image: webpack-bundle-analyzer output]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the webpack bundle analyzer UI, there is a checkbox where you can show the contents of concatenated modules. If you check that box, you will see the contents.

Here is what the UI looks like, where you can toggle the setting: [image]

Here is what it looks like **without** the box checked: [image]

Here is what it looks like **WITH** the box checked: [image]

Comment: @Omtechguy I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see this checkbox in my analyzer, is it a specific version?

Comment: Whatever was the latest on Jun 18, 2019.

Comment: Noticed after asking that if module concatenation is off then I don't see the checkbox :) If concatenation is on the checkbox is there.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are using the [ModuleConcatenationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/), try commenting it out. It's one of the plugins that can obscure this. Here are [more details](https://twitter.com/olore/status/937523005407813632) and the [defect logged](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/115).

Answer (score 1):

Webpack now supports turning off module concatenation:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false,
  },
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationconcatenatemodules

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [Philipp Feigl](https://github.com/pfeigl) suggested [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/115#issuecomment-384965018), I modified my package.json of my Angular 7 cli project.

My application is called ***playpen***, so adjust the location of the stats.json file on your **bundle-report** target.

So dist/***playpen***/stats.json should be dist/{YOURAPP}/stats.json

```
{
  "name": "playpen",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "bundle-report": "ng build --prod --stats-json --build-optimizer=false --vendor-chunk=true --named-chunks=true --output-hashing=media && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/playpen/stats.json"
  },
```